# Unable to solve Run time error in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve a very basic problem from URI online judge in Python 3, I have solved the problem and run on IDE it's showing output as expected but while I'm submitting it's showing `RunTime Error`

**The Problem:**

Make a program that reads three floating point values: A, B and C. Then, calculate and show:

a) the area of the rectangled triangle that has base A and height C.

b) the area of the radius's circle C. (pi = 3.14159)

c) the area of the trapezium which has A and B by base, and C by height.

d) the area of ​​the square that has side B.

e) the area of the rectangle that has sides A and B.

**Input**

The input file contains three double values with one digit after the decimal point.

**Output**

The output file must contain 5 lines of data. Each line corresponds to one of the areas described above, always with a corresponding message (in Portuguese) and one space between the two points and the value. The value calculated must be presented with 3 digits after the decimal point.

[URI Judge link](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1012)

**My Solution**

```
value_of_a = float(input())
value_of_b = float(input())
value_of_c = float(input())
pi = 3.14159

area_of_the_rectangle_triangle = 0.5 * value_of_a * value_of_c
area_of_the_radius_circle = pi * value_of_c * value_of_c
area_of_the_trapezium = 0.5 * (value_of_a + value_of_b) * value_of_c
area_of_the_square = value_of_b * value_of_b
area_of_the_rectangle = value_of_a * value_of_b

print("TRIANGULO: %.3f" % area_of_the_rectangle_triangle)
print("CIRCULO: %.3f" % area_of_the_radius_circle)
print("TRAPEZIO: %.3f" % area_of_the_trapezium)
print("QUADRADO: %.3f" % area_of_the_square)
print("RETANGULO: %.3f" % area_of_the_rectangle)
```

Can any one please tell me where I have made the mistake!

Comment: It looks like you are being provided the three input values on a *single line* - you must not call `input()` more than once.

Comment: Looks like the input is provided as a file - an argument to your script, not as keyboard input. Thus you need to handle it differently.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
inputs = [float(input()) for i in range(3)]
value_of_a = inputs[0]
value_of_b = inputs[1]
value_of_c = inputs[2]
```

or

```
inputs = input()
inputs = [float(value) for value in inputs.split(' ')]
value_of_a = inputs[0]
value_of_b = inputs[1]
value_of_c = inputs[2]
```

Syntax for output

```
 print("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} ".format(area_of_the_rectangle_triangle,area_of_the_radius_circle,area_of_the_trapezium,area_of_the_square,area_of_the_rectangle))
```

Comment: So, is it the solution for avoiding Run time error or this the the better way to get user input ?

Comment: This is one of the solution for your problem statement where your input is given by the compiler in a series of input. i feel the first case should worked for you.

Comment: I have tried both, 1st one running on IDE without any problem but while submitting showing Run Time Error. And 2nd one not running on IDE as i'm using Python3

Comment: try this : print("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} ".format(area_of_the_rectangle_triangle,area_of_the_radius_circle,area_of_the_trapezium,area_of_the_square,area_of_the_rectangle))

Answer (score 0):

You can use input().split() to split multiples variables that were given on a sigle input line.

```
#input 10 a 30
VarA, VarB, VarC = input().split()

#resulting on
#VarA = '10'
#VarB = 'a'
#VarC = '30'
```